# integrating facebook in sharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, content-editor-web-part, sharepoint-integration

I am trying to get post/news-feeds from **Facebook page/group** in my SharePoint page.following are the steps I am doing.

Registered here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts. and then given the the URL of Facebook page. after getting code from here I just copied the hole code in content editor web part.

Referred below link:

- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/facebook-webpart-in-sharepoint1

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>    
<script>(function(d, s, id) {    
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];    
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;    
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;    
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&amp;version=v2.5";    
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);    
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>    
<div class="fb-post" data-href="{your-post-url}"></div>
```

Replace `{your-post-url}` with your posts' `URL`.

Comment: Thanks gaurravs for your reply but it is not working, the group post which i want in is Closed group. it is showing me this message "The Facebook post is no longer available. It may have been removed or the privacy settings of the post may have changed" , now i thing to get post  using Rest API .